# Web-app triage: appending some html to hide broken html

Tags: html, css, web-applications, error-handling

It's possible that a dynamic web app may encounter an error after it began streaming its output html to a web browser. **At the moment of realizing the error, what chunk of html could be appended to the output stream to try to patch the html up into something likely to successfully render a basic error message?**

Consider

- You don't have any buffer of what was recently sent, so you're totally oblivious to what may have been sent.
- Output may have halted at *any location* in an html document, such as in the middle of an html tag, comment, attribute, style, script, etc....

I was thinking a strategy might be to try to close any open contexts by using quotes and various closing tags, and then use absolute positioning on a div to cover the entire view port, hopefully hiding any broken content. For example, I could append the following:

```
"
'
-->
>
</script>
</style>
</div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 10000;">
    My Error Message
</div>
```

Unacceptable answers:

- Answers which suggest to fully buffer the output, so that it can be fully discarded upon realization of an error. Streaming is sometimes desirable, or even necessary.
- Answers which in some fashion suggest to fix the underlying problems causing the error. Robust engineering always plans for the "what if" scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you give is good already, but I would suggest appending `</body>` before your error message - this will prompt the browser to close off as many HTML tags as are open (HTML is designed to deal with missing end tags). That way you don't have to worry about closing potentially dozens of nested divs and your message getting lost somewhere down the page and the absolute positioning (did you mean `fixed`?) being made relative to some other element which has position.